# Set darker transparent background to a label on an image

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have an image and a label on it.

To improve readability I would like the transparent background for the label a little bit darker.

Here's an image to figure out what I'm looking for:

[image]

Any idea how to perform that? I've already tried with Blur transparency but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the background color and transparency for the label in the following way:

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7)
```

To make your background darker set the alpha (transparency) to a higher value. Completely opaque is an alpha of 1.0 and completely transparent is an alpha of 0.0. So experiment around a bit with the alpha until you find a value you like.

Of course you can also adjust the red, green and blue values to a value of your liking. An RGB of 0,0,0 will make the darkest option, black, which may be the most useful for you here.

**Edit:** You can also use the following alternatives to achieve the same effect:

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.7)
```

or

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

**Edit:** In Swift 3 this would be:

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
label.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7]
```

Comment: Please make sure you check the tags of the OP's question. This question is tagged swift and so if the OP tried your code using the Swift compiler, there would be a resultant failure.